# Raspian howto disable doubleclick drag etc

Tags: raspberry-pi2

I'm using a raspberry pi with a touchscreen monitor and chrome (kiosk mode) for displaying a web application. I want to disable the doubleclick, drag support, multitouch etc.
The only thing the user should do via the touchscreen is a simple (single) click.

BTW: To disable the dbclick by the web application is no solution for me. I want to change these mouse settings in raspian.

So my question is: How to change the mouse settings for doubleclick etc. systemwide?

Comment: Might be better to ask on http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/

Comment: ok, thanks – I will do so